# My ELMo trained model gives output dictionary with different fields from those from the tf.hub model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, elmo

When using a pre-trained ElMo model, I get an output dictionary different from the output dictionary explained in the published [tf.hub model](https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2) 
My output dictionary's signature is

```
> model = BidirectionalLanguageModel(options_file, weight_file)
> ids_placeholder = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=(None, None, max_word_length))
> ops = model(ids_placeholder)
> print (ops)
{'token_embeddings': <tf.Tensor 'bilm/Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 512) dtype=float32>, 
'lengths': <tf.Tensor 'sub:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>, 
'mask': <tf.Tensor 'Cast_1:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=bool>, 
'lm_embeddings': <tf.Tensor 'concat_3:0' shape=(?, 3, ?, 1024) dtype=float32>}
```

while the output dictionary from `tf hub` contains:

- word_emb: the character-based word representations with shape [batch_size, max_length, 512].
- lstm_outputs1: the first LSTM hidden state with shape [batch_size, max_length, 1024]
- lstm_outputs2: the second LSTM hidden state with shape [batch_size, max_length, 1024].
- elmo: the weighted sum of the 3 layers, where the weights are trainable. This tensor has shape [batch_size, max_length, 1024]
- default: a fixed mean-pooling of all contextualized word representations with shape [batch_size, 1024].

how can I access the `word_emb, lstm_outputs1, lstm_outputs2 ..` fields in the output dictionary?
I am following the usage example to cache a dataset from [this link](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf/blob/master/bilm/model.py#L655)

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the example from the [tf-Hub website](https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3), you'll see :

```
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3", trainable=True)
embeddings = elmo(
    ["the cat is on the mat", "dogs are in the fog"],
    signature="default",
    as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

Be sure that `as_dict` parameter is set to `True`. 
Here this example directly retrieves the `["elmo"]` value of the dictionary, if you get rid of it :

```
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3", trainable=True)
embeddings = elmo(
    ["the cat is on the mat", "dogs are in the fog"],
    signature="default",
    as_dict=True)
```

the variable elmo created will be the dictionary with the wanted `word_emb, lstm_outputs1, lstm_outputs2 ..` attributes.

Hope this helps !